# How to add [OnDeserialized] functionality to an existing class?

Tags: c#, serialization

```
[OnDeserialized]
public static void OnDeserialized(this List<Bbb> self, StreamingContext context) {
    //special handling
}
```

This extension method obviously doesn't work, but I'd like to provide an [OnDeserialized] implementation for List without being forced to create a subclass with nothing but constructors.

Can this be done another way? Is there an event system that I can hook into instead?

Comment: Yes, the question notes that extension methods are not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are static metadata. Hence they are applied to the `Type` of the class at compile time.

`Extension Methods` by definition are not part of the `Type` and you can't dynamically apply attributes.

Since `List` is a closed type, this cannot be achieved.